# angularjs get current scope from clicked element

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

Here's how I'm getting the scope from a click. Is there an easier way to get the child scope? Thanks.

```
 .chatMsg(ng-repeat='chatMsg in chatLog', ng-class="{active: detailed}",  ng-click="openChatDetail($event)")
    .text {{chatMsg.foo}}

  $scope.openChatDetail = function(e) {
    var childScope = angular.element(e.currentTarget).scope()
    if (childScope.detailed) {
      childScope.detailed = false
      return
    }

    childScope.detailed = true;
  }
```

I'm trying to add an active class to the chat message when it's opened in detailed mode.

Comment: Please provide a little more information regarding what you're trying to do, as reaching across scopes will hinder your ability to unit test your controller. There may be a better approach rather than accessing the child scope directly.

Comment: @Brocco you're right sorry I added that info.

Answer (score 0):

On child scope, emit the event out to its parent scope(s)

```
$scope.$emit('event name', {param: value});
```

and on your parent scope listen for and handle the event

```
$scope.$on('event name', function (params){});
```

[documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/%24rootScope.Scope#%24emit)

Answer (score 0):

If I understood well, `chatMsg` is a directive. It means that you can specify your `openChatDetail` method in the directive's controller, where the scope will be the scope of the directive.

```
yourApp.directive('chatMsg', [
    function(){
        return {
            ...,
            scope: true, /* or even better, isolated scope */
            controller: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
                scope.openChatDetail = function() {
                     ...
                }  
            }
        }
    }
])
```

Answer (score 0):

Why you didn't do this instead:

```
.chatMsg(ng-repeat='chatMsg in chatLog', ng-class="{true: 'active'}[chatMsg.detailed]",  ng-click="openChatDetail(chatMsg)") .text {{chatMsg.foo}}
```

In your **controller**

```
 $scope.openChatDetail = function(item) {
      item.detailed =  !(item.detailed) || true;
  }
```